# How to get value of text wrapped in paragraph element <p> with Selenium in Java

Tags: selenium-webdriver, xpath

I have a button, clicking on it generates a number which is wrapped in paragraph text such as `<p>`random number `<p>` , I want to get that random number value and do operations based on number it generates.

From below I need to get 34,756 number and store it in Java.

Here is the HTML code for it:

```
<div class="form-group">
<div class="alert alert-count">
  <p>
  <b>
<!-- react-text: 531 -->
<!-- /react-text -->
<!-- react-text: 532 -->
 34,756
<!-- /react-text -->
</b>
```

And the XPath I used is as below:

```
String count = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='alert alert-count']/p).getText();
```

But on console it gives error as:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException

Answer (score 2):

Your example code is missing a `"` and a `)` in the `By.xpath`. Guess you would get a syntaxError so your real code might be correct.

Do you wait for the element, because I think the `findElement` returns no object ( e.g. NULL) when it is not displayed (yet) and called `getText()` on a NULL is not possible , resulting in the `NullPointerException`. Read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20903231/how-to-wait-until-an-element-is-present-in-selenium

Keep in mind findElement does not wait for the element, it just fails instantly.

Answer (score 1):

I think the there is a problem with the provided XPath, you are navigating to the paragraph tag `(<p> tag)` and fetching the text, I suggest you navigate to the bold tag `(<b>tag)` and fetch the respective value, like the following:

```
String count = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='alert alert-count']/p/b")).getText();
```

Comment: I think this should work

Comment: Are you sure? In the C# bindings, the Text property gets ALL innerHTML, even from child nodes.

Comment: @FDM What you have said is also true. As Neils, Mentioned the syntax error may also be the case

Answer (score 0):

you can get the text for an HTML tag using the below snippet

```
String count = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='alert alert-count']/p).getAttribute("innerhtml");

System.out.println(count);
```

It will fetch the text inside the HTML and prints it to console.

Comment: missing closing double quotes and bracket this will generate error : String count = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='alert alert-count']/p).getAttribute("innerhtml");

Answer (score 0):

We are providing test automation services to clients and we have tried the below code for getting text of HTML tag:-

```
String count = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='alert alert-count']/p).getAttribute("innerhtml");          //getting text from HTML
    System.out.println(count);              //printing the text
```

Comment: DIDNT close bracket and double quotes generates error 
'WebElement' object has no attribute 'findElement' this will generate Attribute error replace it with driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='alert alert-count']/p").getAttribute("innerhtml")